# How can i switch source in a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 linked servers in our MSSQL-Database.
A function now selects the needed data from the live-server.
What I'd need now in this function would be an option, so I can switch the source from the live-server to the Testserver and back anytime so i do not have to edit the sourcecode everytime before putting it on live.
A union of the data from both servers, where I then filter just the data from source, is not a valid option as the testserver is crappy old and takes forever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Having a function do this could have significant performance impacts. You should have seperate Test and live environments, and the 2 should not overlap.

Comment: This already is the case. however I am looking for a method to spare me the problem of always changing the source of a few dozens of functions and procedures before implementing it into the main database.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to change the source code, as the objects should have the same names in the different environements.

Comment: You are right, but also not. As the test enviroment would have the same names and everything, the source changes also.
For the live system it'd be
select * from Server.database_live.dbo.Items
For the testsystem 
select * from Server.database_test.dob.Items

Comment: *"You are right, but also not."* That doesn't make any sense...They either are, or aren't. Post the DDL of your function, however, the problem you need to solve is to separate your environments.

Comment: OK my guess was wrong, it's not different linked server names, it's different databases. But why do you have different database names in test and live? Because you have them on the same sql server instance? Then you need to separate your environments, exactly as Larnu suggested.

Comment: Use a synonym - which is a database-specific object,

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've re-thought my appearance to the problem and Larnu was right. the sourcecode stays the same. and if I just copy the code without touching the source, I should be fine.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in most cases the performance on this is pretty bad, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't know how to do it. Here's how

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnTestSourceSwitch(@SourceName varchar(100)) RETURNS TABLE as RETURN(
with cteS1 as (
    SELECT Field1, Field2 from prod.dbo.Table1
), cteS2 as (
    SELECT Field1, Field2 from test.dbo.Table1
), cteSwitched as (
    SELECT * FROM cteS1 WHERE @SourceName = 'PROD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM cteS2 WHERE @SourceName = 'TEST'
)
SELECT * FROM cteSwitched
WHERE Field1 = 'Whatever'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the environment variable to execute different blocks of sql. ie:

```
IF @env = 'prod'
BEGIN
   SELECT stuff FROM [ProdLinkedServer].[SCHEMA].[DBNAME].[TABLENAME]
END

IF @env = 'test'
BEGIN
     SELECT stuff FROM [TestLinkedServer].[SCHEMA].[DBNAME].[TABLENAME]
END
```

This means duplicating your code which isn't ideal, but you're working with a function so it should be pretty short.